# Prometheus: coalesce values for missing labels in binary operations

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I have two metrics with matching labels, both counters:

```
accounts_created_total{provider="auth0"} 738
accounts_created_total{provider="google} 980

accounts_deleted_total{provider="auth0"} 65
```

I'd like to calculate the number of existing accounts from those two metrics. I came up with this:

```
accounts_created_total - accounts_deleted_total

# which results in

{provider="auth0"} 673

# Note the missing provider="Google"
```

Unfortunately, there's no `account_deleted_total` for `provider="Google"`, and so I only get the result for `provider="auth0"`.

Is there a way I can tell prometheus to "make up" the missing labels? That would typically be equivalent to a `coalesce` in SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can complete a time serie using the [OR binary operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators):

> vector1 or vector2 results in a vector that contains all original elements
> (label sets + values) of vector1 and additionally all elements of vector2
> which do not have matching label sets in vector1.

Assuming you want to default `accounts_deleted_total` to 0, the following expression uses `accounts_created_total` as second vector to extract the labels and multiplying by 0 ensures the value is reset:

```
accounts_deleted_total OR (accounts_created_total * 0)
```

In the case of `autho0`, the label exists in `accounts_deleted_total` and the second part will not be used ; to the contrary, for `google`, second part will yield

```
{provider="google"} 0
```

Finally, you can use it in your expression:

```
accounts_created_total - (accounts_deleted_total OR (accounts_created_total * 0))
```

In your specific case, since you are using the same metric to extract the labels, you can even simplify the expression to:

```
(accounts_created_total - accounts_deleted_total) OR accounts_created_total
```